# Which is the actual scientific position on the expression of human emotions?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, emotion, social-neuroscience

1. According with **Darwin**'s [“Expression of the Emotions in Man and Animals”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Expression_of_the_Emotions_in_Man_and_Animals): specific emotional states seek to appear on each human being - even on blind people - , with no differences of cultures.
2. According to **James-Lange** theory, the emotional states are the *results* and not the cause, of perceived physiological changes
3. According to **Cannon-Bard** theory, James- Lange theory has some weak points: arousal would not be enough, and would not be necessary, the speed with which we often experience some emotions seems to overcome the speed of body response. Given that they propose that: the external stimulus is processed by the **thalamus**, which sends impulses to the **cortex** - where the emotion is consciously experienced - and sends impulses to the **hypothalamus** - which produces autonomous physiological changes.
4. **Schachter**'s theory partly agree with James-Lange theory: Physiological modifications precede emotional experiences, but we have to decide which particular emotion is, giving cognitively labels to emotions.

### Nowadays which is the accepted theory on emotions by *social neuroscience* ?

*References*

- *The Student's Guide to Social Neuroscience* , Jamie Ward, 2012

Comment: To clarify, are you asking for a general "theory of emotions" or a theory of "emotional expression" (facial and bodily movements that correspond to emotional events)?

Comment: You should be more specific - there is not such a thing as *the* theory of emotion.  Further, the bulleted points are not opposing each other in any way. 1) states that emotional expressions are common (of course blind people cry *etc*); 2) emotional states can be the result of physiology (pain) and can in turn affect physiology (chronic stress etc); 3) It seems you question this part? If that is so please provide the source for your information here and clarify your probem; 4) I don't understand your entry here. What are you trying to say here?